# How to get Kotlin's type safe builders to work in Scala?

Tags: scala, kotlin, dsl, type-safety

Kotlin has awesome [type safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) that make possible to create dsl's like this

```
html {
  head {
    title("The title")
    body {} // compile error
  }
  body {} // fine
}
```

Awesomeness is that you cannot put tags in invalid places, like body inside head, auto-completion also works properly.

I'm interested if this can be achieved in Scala. How to get it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in building html, then there is a library [scalatags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags) that uses similar concept.
Achieving this kind of builders does not need any specific language constructs. Here is an example:

```
object HtmlBuilder extends App {
    import html._
    val result = html {
        div {
            div{
                a(href = "http://stackoverflow.com")
            }
        }
    }
}

sealed trait Node
case class Element(name: String, attrs: Map[String, String], body: Node) extends Node
case class Text(content: String) extends Node
case object Empty extends Node

object html {
    implicit val node: Node = Empty
    def apply(body: Node) = body
    def a(href: String)(implicit body: Node) =
        Element("a", Map("href" -> href), body)
    def div(body: Node) =
        Element("div", Map.empty, body)
}

object Node {
    implicit def strToText(str: String): Text = Text(str)
}
```

Comment: scalatags doesn't fulfill the type-safety requirement.

Comment: @Yaroslav Well, you're right. And it doesn't seem to be a way to make so neat api, at least for now. Some day there will be Dotty with implicit function types http://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2016/12/05/implicit-function-types.html#how-to-remove-boilerplate. They will do exactly what you need.

Comment: @Yaroslav there is one more lib called rapture https://github.com/propensive/rapture. And you can implement type safe templates. The documentation is pure but it works. Here is the example of website https://github.com/propensive/contextual-web/blob/master/src/main/scala/main.scala