# How can I create a DSL involving "blocks" where certain functions are in-scope?

Tags: scala, dsl

#### Overview

I have a Kotlin-based project that defines a DSL, but for reasons given below I'm now investigating whether it would be better to write my project in Scala. As Scala doesn't seem to lend itself to creating DSLs with [as much ease as in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html), I'm not entirely sure how I'd recreate the same DSL in Scala.

Before this gets flagged as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631606/how-to-get-kotlins-type-safe-builders-to-work-in-scala), I've looked at that but my DSL requirements are somewhat different and I haven't been able to figure out a solution from that.

#### Details

I'm trying to create a flow-based programming system for developing automated vehicle part test procedures, and for the past couple of weeks I've been testing out an implementation of this in Kotlin, since it seems to support a lot of features that are really nice for creating FBP systems (native coroutine support, easy creation of DSLs using type-safe builders, etc.).

As awesome as Kotlin is though, I'm starting to realise that it would help a lot if the implementation language for the FBP was more functional, since FBP's seem to share a lot in common with functional languages. In particular, being able to define and consume typeclasses would be really useful for a project like this.

In Kotlin, I've created a DSL representing the "glue" language between nodes in a flow-based system. For example, given the existence of two blackbox processes `Add` and `Square`, I can define a "composite" node that squares the sum of two numbers:

```kotlin
@CompositeNode
private fun CompositeOutputtingScalar<Int>.addAndSquare(x: Int, y: Int) {
    val add = create<Add>()
    val square = create<Square>()

    connect {
        input(x) to add.x
        input(y) to add.y
        add.output to square.input
        square.output to output
    }
}
```

The idea is that `connect` is a function that takes a lambda of form `ConnectionContext.() -> Unit`, where `ConnectionContext` defines various overloads of an infix function `to` (shadowing the built-in `to` function in the Kotlin stdlib) allowing me to define the connections between these processes (or nodes).

This is my attempt to do something similar in Scala:

```
class OutputPort[-A] {
  def connectTo(inputPort: InputPort[A]) {}
}

class InputPort[+A]

object connect {
  val connections = new ListBuffer[Connection[_]]()

  case class Connection[A](outputPort: OutputPort[A], inputPort: InputPort[A])

  class ConnectionTracker() {
    def track[A](connection: Connection[A]) {}
  }

  // Cannot make `OutputPort.connectTo` directly return a `Connection[A]` 
  // without sacrificing covariance, so make an implicit wrapper class
  // that does this instead
  implicit class ExtendedPort[A](outputPort: OutputPort[A]) {
    def |>(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = {
      outputPort connectTo inputPort
      connections += Connection(outputPort, inputPort)
    }
  }
}

def someCompositeFunction() {
  val output = new OutputPort[Int]
  val input = new InputPort[Int]
  output |> input // Should not be valid here

  connect {
    output |> input // Should be valid here
  }
}
```

Right now this won't compile because `ConnectablePort` isn't in scope. I can bring it into scope by doing:

```
import connect._
connect {
  output |> input // Should be valid here
}
```

However, it's undesirable to have to do this within the node definition.

To summarise, how can I recreate the DSL I've made in Kotlin within Scala? For reference, this is how I've defined my Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
interface Composite {
    fun <U : ExecutableNode> create(id: String? = null): U
    fun connect(apply: ConnectionContext.() -> Unit)

    class ConnectionContext {
        val constants = mutableListOf<Constant<*>>()

        fun <T> input(parameter: T): OutputPort<T> = error("Should not actually be invoked after annotation processing")
        fun <T> input(parameterPort: OutputPort<T>) = parameterPort
        fun <T> constant(value: T) = Constant(value.toString(), value)

        infix fun <U, V> U.to(input: InputPort<V>): Nothing = error("Cannot connect value to specified input")
        infix fun <U> OutputPort<U>.to(input: InputPort<U>) = this join input
        infix fun <T, U> T.to(other: U): Nothing = error("Invalid connection")
    }
}

interface CompositeOutputtingScalar<T> : Composite {
    val output: InputPort<T>
}

interface CompositeOutputtingCluster<T : Cluster> : Composite {
    fun <TProperty> output(output: T.() -> TProperty): InputPort<TProperty>
}
```

Comment: Scala 3 will most likely have a feature that enables "type safe builders": http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/implicit-function-types.html

Comment: @Jasper-M That's pretty sweet. Shame that Scala 3 won't release until 2020 at the earliest.

Answer (score 1):

Just turning on the `|>` is pretty straightforward in Scala if you use a companion object, and is something always available with the output port

```
class OutputPort[-A] {
  def connectTo(inputPort: InputPort[A]):Unit = {}
}

class InputPort[+A]

object OutputPort{
    implicit class ConnectablePort[A](outputPort: OutputPort[A]) {
      def |>(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = outputPort connectTo inputPort
    }
}

def someCompositeFunction() {
  val output = new OutputPort[Int]
  val input = new InputPort[Int]
  output |> input // Should be valid here
}
```

Judiciously deciding where to do imports is a core Scala concept.  It is how we turn on `implicit` in our code, like the following, is very common, since that is the way we turn on our type classes.

```
class OutputPort[-A] {
  def connectTo(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = {}
}

class InputPort[+A]

object Converter {
  implicit class ConnectablePort[A](outputPort: OutputPort[A]) {
    def |>(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = outputPort connectTo inputPort
  }
}

def someCompositeFunction() {
  val output = new OutputPort[Int]
  val input = new InputPort[Int]
  import Converter._
  output |> input // Should be valid here
}
```

Now, I think this is what you are looking for, but there are still some `import` and `implicit` that needs to be setup, but this would enclose the `implicit` behavior:

```
class OutputPort[-A] {
    def connectTo(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = {}
}

class InputPort[+A]

object Converter {

    private class ConnectablePort[A](outputPort: OutputPort[A]) {
        def |>(inputPort: InputPort[A]): Unit = outputPort connectTo
            inputPort
    }

    def convert[A](f: (OutputPort[A] => ConnectablePort[A]) => Unit): Unit = {
        def connectablePortWrapper(x: OutputPort[A]): ConnectablePort[A] = new ConnectablePort[A](x)

        f(connectablePortWrapper _)
    }
}

object MyRunner extends App {

    val output = new OutputPort[Int]
    val input = new InputPort[Int]

    import Converter.convert

    //output |> input  won't work
    convert[Int] { implicit wrapper =>
        output |> input // Should be valid here
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for the effort put in and the helpful tips, but that DSL at the bottom does not look very nice compared to the Kotlin equivalent - it involves import statements, and implicit parameters that aren't used. Additionally, the block where I wire up the connections shouldn't be parameterised as the idea is that only the types for each individual connection between two ports need to match, not every connection defined within the block. I'm trying to get something as close as possible to the `addAndSquare` example.

Comment: You're right that I can make `|>` always available using a companion object - I've updated my post with a less-contrived example in which `|>` is more than just an alternative of `connectTo`, and therefore why it might be something I only want to be available within a particular scope. For what it's worth, the [Akka DSL](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/actordsl.html) looks to be doing a similar kind of thing to what I'm after, but I'm still trying to understand how they do it.

Comment: Akka DSL and Akka Streams DSL would be a great way to find examples of what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't know about Akka Streams. Though (from a first impression only) their DSL is slightly uglier than what's possible in Kotlin, so I suppose the bottom line is that the DSL I made in Kotlin is probably not possible to exactly reproduce in Scala, at least as an embedded DSL. It's good to have found that out now, at least.

Comment: @TagC From what I understand Kotlin doesn't have type classes. https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/87  and that having that power is great to have in Scala.  My guess is that if Kotlin would need to make TypeClasses a thing it would have to look like Scala where we have control of our `import` and `implicit`, or in Kotlin's case `extension`. But I am answering out of ignorance of Kotlin since I am not a professional with Kotlin. ;)

Comment: Yeah, Kotlin unfortunately doesn't have typeclasses (yet) and that's why I'm considering the switch. However, it has this concept of function literals with receivers; if the Akka Streams DSL were done in Kotlin, it could probably define `RunnableGraph.fromGraph` to take a lambda parameter of `GraphDSL.Builder.() -> Unit`, making the builder's methods implicitly available via `this.` within the scope of the lambda. In that case, `~>` would be an infix extension method defined in `GraphDSL.Builder`, and you could omit the ugly `implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed]`.